# postgresql: I changed the location and it does not start anymore

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I tried to change the folder location of `postgresql` as suggested [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-postgresql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04)

but if I try:

```
sudo -u postgres psql

psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
```

and the new location is in:

```
/home/database/postgresql
```

Comment: I voted to move this question to ServerFault

Comment: Did you adapt the service that starts PostgreSQL?